# Show input field when other option is selected in multiple select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am trying to store data from multiple select options and its working fine, Now what I am trying to do is when I select another option an input field will appear and will enter the data in it and then store in the database along with other options selected.

I have tried something like this,

```
<select class="form-control select2" name="sectors[]" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);' multiple>
    
    @if(count(get_sectors()) > 0)
    
    @foreach(get_sectors() as $k=>$s)
    
    <option value="{{ $k }}">{{ $s }}</option>
    
    @endforeach
    
    @endif

    <option value="others">others</option>
                        
</select>
<input type="text" name="sectors[]" id="color" style='display:none;'/>
```

Here is the script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckColors(val){
 var element=document.getElementById('color');
 if(val=='pick a color'||val=='others')
   element.style.display='block';
 else  
   element.style.display='none';
}

</script>
```

Please help me out.

Working

```
<select class="form-control select2" name="sectors[]" onchange='CheckColors(this.value);'>
```

Comment: have you check what the value is coming in the method "CheckColors"?

Comment: Actually input field is not appearing also when multiple is added in select option

Comment: you mean to say if you select only single option i.e. "pick a color" or "others" then input field is visible  and when you select more option then input field hide again.Right?

Comment: When I am using above "working section"  then input field is appearing on selecting other

Comment: I think the issue is everytime method call on selecting option so whatever value is selected based on that code is executing.You need to get all the selected option value from dropdown and in that check whether the option is selected on which you have to show the input field.

Comment: Can you please add a code for it

Answer (score 0):

```
function CheckColors(val){
    var element=document.getElementById('color');
    var is_input_field_visible = false;
    $(".select2 option").each(function()
    {
        if($(this).val()=='pick a color'|| $(this).val()=='others'){
            element.style.display='block';
            is_input_field_visible = true;
        }
    });

    if(is_input_field_visible == false){
        element.style.display='none';
    }
}
```

I have not tried the above code but you may check may be it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

the multiple select return value will be as array or just a single value.

for that to get the correct value from multiple array.

you should change your javascript code to.

```
function CheckColors(val){
        // Get selected options by select ID.
        // change #select-multiple to any id in your select box
        let selected = document.querySelectorAll('#select-multiple option:checked');
        // map all selected values as array
        let values = Array.from(selected).map(el => el.value);
        var element=document.getElementById('color');
        if(val=='pick a color'||val=='others' || values.includes('pick a color'))
            element.style.display='block';
        else
            element.style.display='none';
    }
```

in this way you will get the correct value after selecting multiple values or just a single value.

don't forget to give a specific ID to your select box.